# Current SVN project - change hostname

Tags: eclipse, svn

My mate created a project from SVN with bad hostname - `192.168.0.100.` - yes, with a dot at the end. :)

Eclipse created this project, downloaded files, etc but there is problem with commits.

Is it possible to change SVN hostname in this current existing project from `192.168.0.100.` to `192.168.0.100` without creating a new one (from shell or something) ?

**Solution:**

```
svn --relocate switch http://192.168.0.100./project http://192.168.0.100/project .
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the **[svn switch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re27.html)** command to change the location (using the **--relocate** option)

Comment: I got an error:  svn: 'http://192.168.0.100./project'
is not the same repository as
'http://192.168.0.100/project'

Comment: did you use the --relocate switch?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your favorite text search/replace tool and replace "192.168.0.100." with "192.168.0.100" in all the .svn/entries files in all the directories of the project.

Comment: There are no `.svn` directories in my workspace. I have no idea where it stores the hostname...